# Prove the polynomial ring and algebra of quaternions isomorphisms

Tags: quaternions

I saw an answer on a question [Prove the polynomial ring and field isomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170096/prove-the-polynomial-ring-and-field-isomorphisms/2170138#2170138), but 
can somebody explain why with $x=j$ and $ix=k$, the elements $i,j,k$ satisfy all the defining relations they are supposed to for the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would leave a comment at the solution asking for clarification, but here I see you probably don't have the requisite reputation to do so, so this is OK.

You've explained your question in a comment like this:

> $j\cdot i=xi=ix=k$ So, I think the answer isn't correct or I didn't understand something.

Yes, you've misunderstood something. In the solution there, $xi\neq ix$. If you read the posted question more closely, we are working with something called a [twisted polynomial ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_polynomial_ring), where $x\lambda=\alpha(\lambda) x$ where $\alpha$ is a ring homomorphism.  (The post says *skew polynomial ring* but in my mind this describes a more general construction.)

The ring homomorphism in this construction is complex conjugation, so in the twisted polynomial ring described there, $xi=\alpha(i)x=-ix$